# Tablesorter not working using select2 beta

Tags: tablesorter

I'm trying to understand how tablesorter works. 
Now I'm trying to use the select2 beta feature. I've been following the example (mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-select2.html), the source code and some internet examples but I can't do it work correctly. 
The problem I've is that if I take out of my code the *filter_formatter* and the *filter_selectSource* options the other filters works fine, but when I add it they doesn't. When the options are add it only appears the first filter (is not a select2) and the first select2 (by this reason I supposed the error was here but I can't find it). But any more filter appears and any of 2 works correctly.

Any help would be appreciated. I'll add some images at the end.

```
<script src="~/Content/select2/js/select2.full.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/widgets/widget-filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/widgets/widget-filter-formatter-select2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/widgets/widget-headerTitles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/tablesorter-master/js/widgets/widget-output.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var categoryArray = [];
        var languajesArray = [];

        @Code

            For Each categoryElement As String In categoryList
                @<text>
                    categoryArray.push("@categoryElement");
                </text>
            Next

            For Each languajeElement As String In languajeList
                @<text>
                    languajesArray.push("@languajeElement");
                </text>
            Next

        End Code

        $('#tblDoc').tablesorter({
            widgets: ['filter', 'stickyHeaders'], //, 'uitheme'
            debug: true, //Firebug (console) needed --> /docs/example-option-debug.html
            sortMultiSortKey: 'altKey', //Click to sort any column header, then hold down the alt key and select a second column. Continue selecting columns as desired.
            widthFixed: true,
            ignoreCase: false, // if false, upper case sorts BEFORE lower case
            sortList: [[3, 1]], //[[column, asc(0)/desc(1)]]
            widgetOptions: {
                filter_columnFilters: true,
                filter_childRows: false,
                filter_childByColumn: false,
                filter_columnAnyMatch: false, // if true, allows using "#:{query}" in AnyMatch searches (column:query; added v2.20.0)
                filter_cellFilter: '', // extra css class name (string or array) added to the filter element (input or select)
                filter_cssFilter: '', // extra css class name(s) applied to the table row containing the filters & the inputs within that row, this option can either be a string (class applied to all filters) or an array (class applied to indexed filter) or []
                filter_defaultFilter: {}, // add a default column filter type "~{query}" to make fuzzy searches default; "{q1} AND {q2}" to make all searches use a logical AND.
                filter_excludeFilter: {}, // filters to exclude, per column
                filter_external: '', // jQuery selector (or object) pointing to an input to be used to match the contents of any column, please refer to the filter-any-match demo for limitations - new in v2.15
                filter_filteredRow: 'filtered', // class added to filtered rows (rows that are not showing); needed by pager plugin
                filter_formatter: { // add custom filter elements to the filter row, see the filter formatter demos for more specifics

                    1: function ($cell, indx) { //https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-select2.html
                        return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.select2($cell, indx, {
                            match: true,          // adds "filter-match" to header
                            multiple: true,
                            cellText: '',         // Cell text
                            width: '95%',         // adjusted width to allow for cell text
                            value: [],            // initial select2 values
                        });
                    },

                    2: function ($cell, indx) { 
                        return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.select2($cell, indx, {
                            match: true,           // adds "filter-match" to header
                            multiple: true,
                            cellText: '',          // Cell text
                            width: '95%',          // adjusted width to allow for cell text
                            value: [],             // initial select2 values
                        });
                    }

                },
                filter_functions: null,// add custom filter functions using this option, see the filter widget custom demo for more specifics on how to use this option  
                filter_hideEmpty: true, // hide filter row when table is empty
                filter_hideFilters: false, // if true, filters are collapsed initially, but can be revealed by hovering over the grey bar immediately, below the header row. Additionally, tabbing through the document will open the filter row when an input gets focus
                filter_ignoreCase: true, // Set this option to false to make the searches case sensitive
                filter_liveSearch: true, // if true, search column content while the user types (with a delay)
                filter_onlyAvail: 'filter-onlyAvail', // a header with a select dropdown & this class name will only show available (visible) options within that drop down.
                filter_placeholder: { search: '', select: '' }, // default placeholder text (overridden by any header "data-placeholder" setting)
                //filter_reset : 'button.reset', // jQuery selector string of an element used to reset the filter
                filter_saveFilters: true, // Use the $.tablesorter.storage utility to save the most recent filters (default setting is false)
                filter_searchDelay: 300, // Delay in milliseconds before the filter widget starts searching; This option prevents searching for, every character while typing and should make searching large tables faster.
                filter_searchFiltered: true, // allow searching through already filtered rows in special circumstances; will speed up searching in large tables if true
                filter_selectSource:  // include a function to return an array of values to be added to the column filter select; make sure to include "filter-match" class otherwise you'll get no results (exact match is default) http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4406/
                {
                    // added as select2 options (you could also use select2 data option)
                    1: function (table, column) {
                        return categoryArray;
                    },

                    2: function (table, column) {
                        return languajesArray;
                    }
                },
                filter_serversideFiltering: false, // if true, server-side filtering should be performed because client-side filtering will be disabled, but the ui and events will still be used.
                filter_startsWith: false, // Set this option to true to use the filter to find text from the start of the column, So typing in "a" will find "albert" but not "frank", both have a's; default is false
                filter_useParsedData: false, // Filter using parsed content for ALL columns, be careful on using this on date columns as the date is parsed and stored as time in seconds
                filter_defaultAttrib: 'data-value', // data attribute in the header cell that contains the default filter value
                filter_selectSourceSeparator: '|', // filter_selectSource array text left of the separator is added to the option value, right into the option text
                stickyHeaders: '', // extra class name added to the sticky header row
                stickyHeaders_offset: 0, // number or jquery selector targeting the position:fixed element
                stickyHeaders_addResizeEvent: true, // trigger "resize" event on headers --> problems resizing and sticky
                stickyHeaders_includeCaption: true, // if false and a caption exist, it won't be included in the sticky header
                stickyHeaders_zIndex: 2, // The zIndex of the stickyHeaders, allows the user to adjust this to their needs
                stickyHeaders_attachTo: null,  // jQuery selector or object to attach sticky header to
                stickyHeaders_xScroll: null, // jQuery selector or object to monitor horizontal scroll position (defaults: xScroll > attachTo > window)
                stickyHeaders_yScroll: null, // jQuery selector or object to monitor vertical scroll position (defaults: yScroll > attachTo > window)
                stickyHeaders_filteredToTop: true // scroll table top into view after filtering
            }
        });

        //Filters style
        $(".tablesorter-filter").addClass("searchStyle");

    });

</script>
```

```
<div class="wrapperOverflow">

    <table id="tblDoc" class="tablesorter">

        @*HEAD*@
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="thDocTitle" class="filter-match textAlignCenter cutStrings">@ViewData("Titulo")</th>
                <th id="thCategory" class="filter-match textAlignCenter cutStrings">@ViewData("Category")</th>
                <th id="thLanguage" class="filter-match textAlignCenter cutStrings">@ViewData("Language")</th>
                <th id="thDatePubl" class="filter-match textAlignCenter cutStrings @strDateFormat">@ViewData("DatePub")</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

I'm obtaining these errors in the console:

```
The select2('val') method was called on an element that is not using Select2.a.fn.select2 @ select2.full.min.js:3
select2.full.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
```

http://subefotos.com/ver/?45cbc45ec22a07843427443ff7d04f2fo.jpg

Without *filter_formatter* and the *filter_selectSource*

http://subefotos.com/ver/?ec622c64ba43c5dba03c156465b5e497o.jpg

Comment: Currently the `widget-filter-formatter-select2.js` only supports the select2 plugin < v4.0 due to recent changes. In the future, I plan on replacing the entire filter formatter option with a new method which should work much easier than the current method. I don't have a timeline for when that feature will be available.

Comment: @Mottie I've changed select2 (https://github.com/select2/select2/tags) to version 3.5.2 and occurs exactly the same. Now appears the error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).appendTo(...).select2 is not a function.  Is failing here: `// add a select2 hidden input!
 $('<input class="select2 select2-' + indx + '" type="hidden" />')
  .val(o.value)
  .appendTo($cell)
  .select2(o)
  .bind('change', function(){
   updateSelect2();
  });` In the .select2(o) line. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mottie I don't mind if I can solve or not because I'm trying to understand how it works to be able to use it as I should, if I can't, I'll search another solution, but this error may be can help you in a future. Regards.